# Issues with eventListeners in Corona SDK, lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Im having a problem creating a event in my program. when I try running it with  the following system setup i get the error "attempt to call method 'addEventListener (a nil value)"  The effect im looking for is the OtherObject file sends a signal,the event, to the Object file telling the particular instance it has finished some task in the OtherObject file.  Any help or guidance to get me on the right path will be very much appreciated.

### Object File

```
Object = {};

ObjectMeta = {__index = Object};

function Object:onTrigger()
   --Event Triggered
end

function Object.new(args)
    Obj = {};
    Obj.sprite = display.newImage("Picture.png");
    Object.someObject = OtherObject.new(args);
    Object.someObject.owner = Object;
    Object:addEventListener("onTriggered", Obj);
    return setmetatable(Obj,ObjectMeta );
end





return Object;
```

### OtherObject File

```
OtherObject = {};

OtherObjectMeta = {__index = OtherObject};

function OtherObject.new(args)
    Obj = {};
    Obj.sprite = display.newRect(0,0,3,7);
    Obj.ObjectImAttachedTo =nil;
    return setmetatable(Obj,OtherObjectMeta );
end
function OtherObject:doSomething()
    self.ObjectImAttachedTo:dispatchEvent( {name = "triggered"} );
end
return OtherObject;
```

Comment: `:addEventListener()` is only applicable to `Runtime` and objects created with `display.newImage()`.

Comment: I just updated my code to include the display.newImage() calls in both objects yet im left with the same issue as before

Comment: As before, you are applying `addEventListener` to your class which doesn't have `addEventListener` method.

Comment: So how would i go about making an addEventListener and dispatchEvent funciton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local Object = {}

local ObjectMeta = {__index = Object}

function Object:triggered(event)
   --Event Triggered
end

function Object.new(args)
    local Obj = {}
    Obj.someObject = OtherObject.new(args)
    Obj.someObject.ObjectImAttachedTo = Obj
    setmetatable(Obj, ObjectMeta)
    Runtime:addEventListener("triggered", Obj)
    return Obj
end

return Object
```

Comment: So how would I dispatch it from OtherObject?  Im not getting errors if I add in your suggestion.  However Its not hitting the event function at al.

Comment: Show your code.  BTW, there is a typo in OtherObject module - wrong metatable in `return setmetatable(Obj,ObjectMeta);`

Comment: I found out my issue, it works correctly now and i updated the code. Thanks for all your help